# Linker error when connecting C to mysql

Tags: mysql, c, windows, visual-c++

i want to connect C to mysql using the following code:

```
#include <C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include\my_global.h>
#include <C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include\mysql.h>

#include <stdio.h> 
MYSQL *conn;    /* pointer to connection handler */

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    conn = mysql_init ( NULL );
    mysql_real_connect (
            conn,"localhost","root","","operator", 3306, NULL,0 );        
    mysql_close ( conn );
    return 0;
}
```

When i try to compile ,i get:

```
Error   3   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mysql_real_connect@32 referenced in function _main   C:\Users\kristel\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\database\database\database.obj   database

Error   4   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mysql_init@4 referenced in function _main    C:\Users\kristel\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\database\database\database.obj   database
```

It seems like something is missing but i dont know when.

[image]

I have added the mysqllib.lib like in the picture but still the problem is not resolved.
**Just another question:** Doing my searches,i have found something concerning cmake.Is there any relation between my error and cmake?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you have included the mySQL header files in your code, you haven't included the mySQL library in your link options.

Comment: i have added :libmysql and mysqlclient.Is there another input i have to add?